# How to I call post api in requests python?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have an API which takes three parameter, Two are strings, while third is a file named "content".

```
from datetime import date

AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
fileName = "a.txt"
FolderID = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
myfiles = {'file': ('report.xls', open('C:\\Users\\Nawaf Momin\\Desktop\\a.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
URL = "https://apidocs.zoho.com/files/v1/upload?authtoken=" + AuthToken + "&scope=docsapi"
mydata = {
    'filename': fileName,
    'fid': FolderID,
    'content': myfiles
}
r = requests.post(url=URL, data=mydata)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

for api documentation visit :https://www.zoho.com/docs/zoho-docs-api.html 
its upload post api..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
`myfiles = {'file': ('report.xls', open('C:\\Users\\Nawaf Momin\\Desktop\\a.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}`
here I sent `parameter_name` instead of `file`. 
so now it looks like `myfiles = {'parametername': ('report.xls', open('pathToFile', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}`

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate the error you are getting so I assume the file content is not showing up. You probably should put the file content separately and add headers to it, also you need to install and import the requests library as it is not built in.

```
from datetime import date
import requests

headers = {
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0" #you will need to complete this user agent yourself
}

AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
fileName = "a.txt"
FolderID = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
myfiles = {'file': ('report.xls', open('C:\\Users\\Nawaf Momin\\Desktop\\a.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
URL = "https://apidocs.zoho.com/files/v1/upload

params = {
authtoken":AuthToken,
"scope":"docsapi"
}

r = requests.post(url=URL,  params=params, files=myfile, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Hope this helped